# Piping file to expressjs and res as json

Tags: json, node.js, express, stream, pipe

Quick question guys. I think i got the logic down but I am messed up because express doesnt have a pipe method?

anyways, I have this for my express endpoint

```
app.get('/:report/top', function(req, res) {
    readDataTop(global[req.params.report], function(err, obj) {
    res.header("Cache-Control", "max-age=3600");
    res.json(obj);
    });
});
```

and currently i am doing this to get data for it.

```
function readDataTop (x, callback) {
    console.log("Read "+x[6]+" and Sent Cached Top Half");
    jf.readFile( "loadedreports/top"+x[6], 'utf8', callback);
};
```

(jf just makes writing json.parse and with try/catch blocks easier) anyways I want to instead of just using fs.readfile i want to open a stream because these files are getting huge.

How would I pipe stuff to express but still use json?
Something like this?

```
function readDataTop (x, callback) {
    console.log("Read "+x[6]+" and Sent Cached Top Half");
    var rstream = fs.createReadStream("loadedreports/top"+req.params.report+".json");
        rstream.pipe(callback); 
};
```

Any ideas? Req is undefined but I thought im passing it through the pipe correctly?

Comment: What you're doing doesn't make sense. The gist is this: your `callback` expects the whole file/object in memory, so that will have to change as well. If you want streams then you need streams "all the way thru". Instead of a callback you would have another stream which will process one "row"/"datum"/"result" as they come, pipe it to another stream (who may write, or aggregate, etc...)

Comment: So i have to pipe it into a writestream and have express listen for the data events? Then on each data event express res.json that line? Will that give me the full json as one object?

I basically want Node to read the file, stream it to express which streams it out on ajax request. The client side should just be seeing a JSON object loading and when its fully received then do something with it. Is that possible?